# How to enable atom-racer documentation in popup list?

Tags: rust, atom-editor

The popup list works, but doesn't display the documentation of the selected item.

In package settings the "Show Documentation" and "Include Signature in Documentation" options are enabled.

[image]

How to make it look like this?

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qzed/autocomplete-racer/master/img/demo.png]

I'm using:

- autocomplete-racer 0.1.3
- Racer 2.0.6
- Atom 1.13.1
- Rust 1.16.0
- Gentoo x86_64

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't figured this out, simply try disabling or uninstalling the `racer` package.

The `autocomplete-racer` package implements its own autocomplete provider which includes the documentation you're after. Based on what you're reporting, the `racer` package is probably taking precedence and as such you'd be limited to its autocomplete provider. Use one or the other, not both.